# How to handle xamarin android push notification click handler when application is not running on backgroud

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.android

I am try to navigate to specific screen when user click on push notification. It's works fine when application is running in background but when I remove application from background while click on push notification it is navigate to first page of the application instead of specific page. Please suggest any idea to navigate to specific page when application is not running in background also.

Answer (score 1):

I used below Code and working fine for me

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, typeof(SpecificActiivty));
 i.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
 PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, i, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
 builder.SetContentIntent(intent);
```

**MyEdited Answer**

```
namespace Example
{
    [Service]
    public class GcmService : GcmServiceBase
    {

        protected override void OnMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
              NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
              Intent i;
              DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
              i = new Intent(context, typeof(SpecificActiivty));
              i.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
              PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, i, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
              builder.SetContentIntent(intent);
              builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_notificationicon);

              builder.SetAutoCancel(true);
              Notification notification = builder.Build();
              builder.SetSound(Settings.System.DefaultNotificationUri);
              Android.Net.Uri notify = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
              Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(context, notify);
              r.Play();
              NotificationManager nm = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
              int customid = date.Day + date.Month + date.Hour + date.Minute + date.Millisecond;
              nm.Notify(customid, notification);
        }
    }
}
```

Here **SpecificActiivty** is your specific page which you want to open on the tap of notification

Comment: Thanks sunita, where I can add this code and what is that specific activity.